# How to get value from JSON object of format {key:value}?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

My API returns a response of following format---

```
".expires" = "Tue, 10 May 2016 07:07:45 GMT";

".issued" = "Tue, 26 Apr 2016 07:07:45 GMT";
Contact = "{ContactID:1172588}";
User = "{\"CreatedByUser\":\"\",\"UserID\":\"8104\",\"FirstName\":\"Rokon\",\"LastName\":\"Uddin\"}";
```

***The problem is I can parse "User" but can not parse "Contact" and can not get value for key ContactID ***

Comment: does the server simply returns string ?

Comment: is this the actual response from the api?

Comment: What format is that?

Comment: Print response in console and paste here!

Answer (score 0):

you can parse like this

```
//Contact = "{ContactID:1172588}";

NSString *contactid =   yourDic[@"Contact"][@"ContactID"];
```

/************** More detail code *********/

```
NSDictionary *contactIdDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1172588",@"ContactID", nil];

NSDictionary *contactDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:contactIdDic,@"Contact", nil];

NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:contactDic options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"output:%@",jsonString);//output: {"Contact":{"ContactID":"1172588"}}

NSString *contactid =   contactDic[@"Contact"][@"ContactID"];
NSLog(@"contactid = %@",contactid); //output = 1172588
```

Comment: Can you add more code? What is yourDic variable, how are you get it?

Comment: just copy and paste code detail and see the observe the out to analize

Comment: Sorry but in your code, you've generate different input data: < output: {"Contact":{"ContactID":"1172588"}} >

Comment: what is the difference?

Comment: difference is valid and not valid JSON :) Try to validate original string with some json validator.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110233/discussion-between-jamil-and-andrew-romanov).

Comment: Shared code snippet is copy past from response  NSLog.

Answer (score 0):

You can not parse Contact because, inside commas you have no valid JSON. I think you tried to parse it as JSON.

You can to correct it by adding commas to any word in the Contact value:

```
 Contact = "{\"ContactID\":1172588}";
```